# LINQ to XML - Get collection of specific values filtered by attribute name

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I need to get a collection of all values from all nodes with a specified attribute name. For instance, from the XML below, I need a collection of values from all nodes in which Country is one of the variables:

```
CAN
true
false
US
true
false
MEX
true
false
```

I have fiddled with this for hours and looked at all the MSDN examples I can find and I'm coming up empty.

UPDATE:
I'm going to keep updating this as I make progress. Managed to get an update to the XML that makes filtering a lot simpler and updated my query too. Issue now is that I only get the first node instead of a collection of all nodes with Name="Country"

FINAL UPDATE: Problem solved. See my answer below. Happy to see any recommended improvements though.

This is the XML I am given to work with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <FoobarData ReportId="0cd8eacf-b577-4974-ae15-1496c5ec06b8">
    <FoobarInfo>
      <PreparedBy>Bob Boozer</PreparedBy>
      <ReviewedBy>Connie Careful</ReviewedBy>
    </FoobarInfo>
    <FoobarFoos>
      <Foo>
        <FooVariables>
          <FooVariable VariableName="Country">
            <VariableValue>CAN</VariableValue>
            <VariableIsRed>true</VariableIsRed>
            <VariableIsHappy>false</VariableIsHappy>
          </FooVariable>
          <FooVariable VariableName="Company">
            <VariableValue>Company A</VariableValue>
            <VariableIsRed>true</VariableIsRed>
            <VariableIsHappy>false</VariableIsHappy>
          </FooVariable>
          <FooVariable VariableName="DaysWithoutInjury">
            <VariableValue>11203</VariableValue>
            <VariableIsRed>false</VariableIsRed>
            <VariableIsHappy>false</VariableIsHappy>
          </FooVariable>
          <FooVariable VariableName="DaysSinceBigMeeting">
            <VariableValue>857</VariableValue>
            <VariableIsRed>false</VariableIsRed>
            <VariableIsHappy>true</VariableIsHappy>
          </FooVariable>
        </FooVariables>
      </Foo>
      <Foo>
        <FooVariables>
          <FooVariable VariableName="Country">
            <VariableValue>US</VariableValue>
            <VariableIsRed>true</VariableIsRed>
            <VariableIsHappy>false</VariableIsHappy>
          </FooVariable>
          <FooVariable VariableName="Company">
            <VariableValue>Company B</VariableValue>
            <VariableIsRed>true</VariableIsRed>
            <VariableIsHappy>false</VariableIsHappy>
          </FooVariable>
          <FooVariable VariableName="DaysWithoutInjury">
            <VariableValue>976</VariableValue>
            <VariableIsRed>false</VariableIsRed>
            <VariableIsHappy>false</VariableIsHappy>
          </FooVariable>
          <FooVariable VariableName="DaysSinceBigMeeting">
            <VariableValue>780</VariableValue>
            <VariableIsRed>false</VariableIsRed>
            <VariableIsHappy>true</VariableIsHappy>
          </FooVariable>
        </FooVariables>
      </Foo>
      <Foo>
        <FooVariables>
          <FooVariable VariableName="Country">
            <VariableValue>MEX</VariableValue>
            <VariableIsRed>true</VariableIsRed>
            <VariableIsHappy>false</VariableIsHappy>
          </FooVariable>
          <FooVariable VariableName="Company">
            <VariableValue>Company C</VariableValue>
            <VariableIsRed>true</VariableIsRed>
            <VariableIsHappy>false</VariableIsHappy>
          </FooVariable>
          <FooVariable VariableName="DaysWithoutInjury">
            <VariableValue>1455</VariableValue>
            <VariableIsRed>false</VariableIsRed>
            <VariableIsHappy>false</VariableIsHappy>
          </FooVariable>
          <FooVariable VariableName="DaysSinceBigMeeting">
            <VariableValue>580</VariableValue>
            <VariableIsRed>false</VariableIsRed>
            <VariableIsHappy>true</VariableIsHappy>
          </FooVariable>
        </FooVariables>
      </Foo>
    </FoobarFoos>
  </FoobarData>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
    var fileData = XElement.Load(srcFile1);
    var xElement1 = fileData.Element("FoobarFoos");
    if (xElement1 != null)
    {
        var element1 = xElement1.Element("Foo");
        if (element1 != null)
        {
            var xElement =
                element1.Element("FooVariables");
            if (xElement != null)
            {
                var variableCollection = 
                    from element in fileData.Descendants("FooVariable")
                    where (string) element.Attribute("VariableName").Value == "Country"
                    select element;
            }
        }
    }
```

Produces:

```
<FooVariable VariableName="Country">
  <VariableValue>CAN</VariableValue>
  <VariableIsRed>true</VariableIsRed>
  <VariableIsHappy>false</VariableIsHappy>
</FooVariable>
<FooVariable VariableName="Country">
  <VariableValue>US</VariableValue>
  <VariableIsRed>true</VariableIsRed>
  <VariableIsHappy>false</VariableIsHappy>
</FooVariable>
<FooVariable VariableName="Country">
  <VariableValue>MEX</VariableValue>
  <VariableIsRed>true</VariableIsRed>
  <VariableIsHappy>false</VariableIsHappy>
</FooVariable>
```